# Image and text displays separately in listview-Android Using Image Loader

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am trying to load image and text via url using imageLoader When i populate it in listview
Image and text are separated When Displaying[image]

Here is my code

```
mall=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("text");
      mallpos=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Ima");
      System.out.println("Images"+mallpos);

      System.out.println(mall.size());
      for(int i=0;i<mall.size();i++)
      {
          poss=mall.get(i);
          System.out.println("value"+poss);
          dto =new locationdto();
          dto.setMallname(poss);
          rou.add(dto);

      }
      System.out.println(mallpos.size());
      for(int i=0;i<mallpos.size();i++)
      {
          Ima=mallpos.get(i);
          System.out.println("value"+Ima);
          dto=new locationdto();
          dto.setImage(Ima);
          System.out.println("imaghe"+ dto.getImage());
          rou.add(dto);

      }

      lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listm);


      System.out.println("Arraysize#############" + rou.size());
      System.out.println("Arraysize#############" + rou1.size());

      MaterialMasterAdapter adapteer =new MaterialMasterAdapter(MalllistActivity.this, rou);
      lv.setAdapter(adapteer);
```

Here is my Adapter code,I Couldn't rectify the error

```
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MaterialMasterAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    Holder mHolder = null;
    private Context mContext;
    locationdto dto = new locationdto();
    ArrayList<locationdto> a1;
    ArrayList<locationdto> arr =new ArrayList<locationdto>();

    String a2;
    String[] imageurl=null;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

String s;
String urlss;

    public MaterialMasterAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<locationdto> arrList1   ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext=c;
        a1=arrList1;
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return a1.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return a1.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        if (child == null) 
        {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();         
            mHolder.txtitemid = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            mHolder. imageView = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

            child.setTag(mHolder);

        } else 
        {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }

        dto=a1.get(pos);
        String url=dto.getImage();


        mHolder.txtitemid.setText(dto.getMallname());
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, mHolder.imageView);

        return child;
    }


    public class Holder 
    {
        TextView txtitemid,txtmat,txtqty,image;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your adapter's code too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017779/how-to-concat-2-arraylists   this linked helped me to concatenate 2 arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concatenated two arraylist into single one  `

```
 if (mall.size()  != mallpos.size()) { // Too many names, or too many numbers
            // Fail
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mall.size(); i++) { // Loop through every name/phone number combo
            array3.add(mall.get(i) + " " + mallpos.get(i)); // Concat the two, and add it
            v=mall.get(i);
            n=mallpos.get(i);
            dto =new locationdto();
              dto.setMallname(v);
              dto.setImage(n);

              rou.add(dto);

        }
```

Refered from [how-to-concat-2-arraylists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017779/how-to-concat-2-arraylists)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, you add items successfully in your ArrayList rou: You loop on the texts first and each time, you add an object. And then, you loop on the images (I suppose) and you add new objects with only images...

Why don't you use an Object, that would contain both image and text inside?
Something like that:

```
public class MyObject{
public final String mText;
public final String mImageUrl;
public MyObject(String text, String image){
mText = text;
mImageUrl = image;
}
}
```

Then (even if I think it would be better to instanciate you object in the previous activity and implement Parcelable in you MyObject class), you will send your ArrayList in your adapter...

Edit: Because in your current code: you have an entry for each text AND an entry for each image, separatly...

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code didn't gave proper info but as per my understanding you can follow this.
In your get view method of adapter define text view and image view.
while calling this adapter send your data which contains both image and text.
just see this.

```
 public class MyItemsAdapter {
 ArrayList<UploadItem> dataList;
 Context context;
 public MyitemListAdapter2(ArrayList<UploadItem> list,Context con){
    this.dataList = list;
    this.context = con;     
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new             ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    im = ImageLoader.getInstance();         
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

 @Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final UploadItem thisItem = dataList.get(position);
      if(convertView == null){          
        convertView =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item_list_row2, parent,false);
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ImageView image = (ImageView_ convertView.findViewByID(R.id.image);

    String path = thisItem.get(position).getImagePath();
    im.displayImage(path, image);
    text.setText(thisItem.getDescritption());
  } 
  }
```

call the adapter by sending required data. and set to list view.
here am using universal image loader to load images asynchronously..you also use other loader as per your wish
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually the thing is that you send the rou to your Adapter class you initailize the two for loop first loop just Adding the two String in rou in list item And second loop Adding two Image View in the List View you Are Adding both thing Seperately

Comment: And i m sure you mall.size is also 2