# How to combine List String array to single array android

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I want to combine two List Array into a Array single one.

first List looks like this:

```
List<String> first   = new ArrayList<String>();
{a,s,d,f,g,h}
```

second list looks like this:

```
List<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();
{z,x,c,v,b}
```

I did the following:

```
ArrayList<String> combine   = new ArrayList<String>();

combine.addall(first);

combine.addall(second);

{a,s,d,f,g,h,z,x,c,v,b}
```

But I want to combine both to be as

```
{{a,s,d,f,g,h},{z,x,c,v,b}}
```

How to do this in Java?

Comment: Sorry pal, nobody knows; and nobody ever asked such questions before; or wrote a tutorial or a book regarding such basic questions. OK; lets avoid the sarcasm: the idea of SO is to **help** you solve your problems yourself. The expectation is that you at least **tried** to do it yourself. And well, you are not showing any evidence of that.

Comment: i tried arraylist but it add all list  {a,s,d,f,g,h,z,x,c,v,b} ArrayList<String> firstname1   = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: just go to this link [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14017809/2715073)

Comment: @clairvoyant I tried that but I want this type of array {{a,s,d,f,g,h},{z,x,c,v,b}} not  {a,s,d,f,g,h,z,x,c,v,b}

Comment: You're going to need a `List<List<String>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
ArrayList<String> l1=new ArrayList<String>();
l1.add("a");
ArrayList<String> l2=new ArrayList<String>();
l1.add("z");
List<ArrayList<String>> l3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
l3.add(l1);
l3.add(l2);
```

`l1` and `l2` are lists of strings, while `l3` is a list of *listOfStrings*.

But are you sure you really want to do that? What about multidimensional arrays?

Comment: Thank you.... Very much its correct. Currently I'm working on X Y coordinates and each line store in array but I'm not able to Identify  each line that's why I asked this.question.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your problem, but working with coordinates should be easier using simple arrays, as you can refer to elements by using... coordinates!

Comment: Currently I'm working with canvas in Java and JavaScript also and I want to draw with X Y coordinates that's why I identify each line to draw again. I draw one line then add in array but if I undo then remove last added array. and  I also add flag with  X Y coordinate to identify staring point that's why I'm using List String.